# FarManager and Tab completion

Tags: far-manager

I am learning Far 3.0 and since the Tab key is mapped to pane swapping, how can you auto-complete paths when typing on the Far command line? I tried some plugins, but none of them worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Far has internal autocomplete feature. F9 -> Options -> Command line settings. You may also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>to access completion dialog.
2. There is [YAC](http://forum.farmanager.com/viewtopic.php?p=31346#p31346) plugin. However, it was written for Far 2.x and requires [Far3Wrap](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Far3Wrapper) if you want to use it in Far 3.x. Please note, Far3wrap was not adopted yet to the latest changes of Far 3.x, so build 2798 or lower required.